# subtracting these two coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am given three natural numbers $n>x\geq k$ and trying to find the value of
$$
\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-x}{k}
$$

I reached the following and not sure if I'm in the right path;
$$
\frac{n!-(n-x)!\prod\limits_{i=1}{x}(n-x-k+i)}{k!(n-k)!\prod\limits_{i=1}{x}(n-x-k+i)}
$$

I only need some hints so I can do it by myself. I also would like if someone give me a hint over the largest value of k (for a fixed $x$) where the result of subtraction will be more than the half of $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Do you have reason to expect there to be a cleaner way to write the expression than simply $\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-x}{k}$?  That seems pretty clean as it is...

Comment: @JMoravitz only my ignorance in such expressions. I felt there should be some closed form of the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

It is already neat, but if you insist on changing it:
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-x+x}{k}=\frac{(n-x)!(n-x+1)\cdots n}{(n-x-k)!(n-x-k+1)...(n-k)k!}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}
$$

and

$$
\binom{n-x}{k}=\frac{(n-x)!}{(n-x-k)!k!}\\
$$
Therefore

$$
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-x}{k}&=\frac{(n-x)!}{(n-x-k)!k!}\left(\frac{(n-x+1)\cdots n}{(n-x-k+1)...(n-k)}-1 \right)\\[10pt]
&=\binom{n-x}{k}\left(\frac{P(n,x)}{P(n-k,x)}-1 \right)
\end{align}
$$

where $$P(n,k)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$